# Nextjs - getServerSideProps not reading query param in production

Tags: javascript, search, next.js, url-parameters

Hope you are well.

I am working on a Next.js project, we have a searchbar in the homepage whose method is located inside the file /pages/search.page.tsx and it runs through the getServerSideProps method.

We came into this bug that affects the search results pagination in production, not any issue in local development or local build.

Basically once a search query is executed the app renders the first bunch of results at: https://www.example.com/search/?s=what-you-have-searched/
So far so good.
However when we try to go ahead with the page results, it keeps rendering the first page because the 'skip' param is not read/received even if it appears in the url like so:
https://www.example.com/search/?s=what-you-have-searched&**skip=15**&type=articolo%2Cgallery%2Cvideo/

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ query }) => {
  const apolloClient = initializeApollo();
  const typeNews = [TypeContent.NEWS, TypeContent.PHOTO, TypeContent.VIDEO];
 
  const fieldValue = query?.s || "";
  const skip = +query?.skip || 0;
  const type = query?.type || typeNews.join(",");

  const params = getParams(fieldValue, type, skip);

  const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
    query: GET_CONTENTS,
    variables: { ...params },
  });
  return {
    props: {
      postData: {
        data
      },
    },
  };
};
```

As mentioned above, we do not have any issue locally running the app through

> yarn dev or yarn start

the bug shows up only when in production.
Basically the 'skip' url params destructured from the object query always return 0 even if the url contains a different value.

What might be wrong?
How can i debug it in production to see what values we receive from the query object?
Thanks

Comment: _"How can i debug it in production to see what values we receive from the query object?"_ - Can't you log the values to the console and see the output on the server's logs?

Comment: @juliomalves did not considered this as we are not connected with the backend team. But thanks

Comment: Oh no, I didn't mean the API server, I meant the Next.js server - so you can debug what's happening inside `getServerSideProps`.

Comment: @juliomalves sorry for the silly question but where can i read the Next.js server log in production? I thought they uploaded the built version

Comment: It depends, where are you hosting your app in production?